# Reduce the color depth in Mips

Tags: image, mips

i want to reduce the color depth of a specific picture in my mips code with this function:

```
quantize:

#a0 - Bildadresse
#a1 - Höhe | height
#a2 - Breite | width
#a3 - n

move $t0 , $a0
move $t1 , $a1
move $t2 , $a2
move $t3 , $a3

li $t5 , 0
li $t7 , 0
mul $t8 , $t1, $t2
li $t9 , 2

while:
beq $t7, $t8, end_while
lb $t6 , 0($t0)
#andi $t6, $t6, 0x0F    
    while_pot:
    beq $t5 , $t3, end_while_pot
    div $t6 , $t9
    mflo $t6
    addi $t5, $t5 , 1
    j while_pot
end_while_pot:
sb $t6 , random($t7)
addi $t0 , $t0 , 1
addi $t7 , $t7 , 1
j while

end_while:
la $s7, random
jr $ra
```

I have to reduce the depth by 2^n bytes but im just getting something confusing.

Result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWfX0.jpg)

original picture: [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpMWk.jpg)

do i something wrong or is this the right way to reduce the width?
If i need something to add for your understanding, please just tell me

Ty for your help :D

Comment: Hey,  is their something else that i habe to change in my code? Or is it working Mike this? Im asking this because Ehen i change THW depth from 255 to 64 nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You only clear `$t5` once in your code, and that's before your while loop. By the way, you could've found this pretty easily if you had used a debugger.

More importantly, that `while_pot` loop is unnecessary and can be replaced by a single instruction: `srlv $t6,$t6,$t3`.